# nodejs child_process.spawn cmd.exe stdin appearing in stdout

Tags: node.js, stdout, stdin, stdio, child-process

I need output of some commands to a node process on a windows machine.

I'm creating cmd.exe child process and trying to interact with it. I need cmd.exe to remain open since i have multiple inter dependable commands (which use PATH, Current Directory) to run.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/K']);
    // '/K' is passed to avoid cmd.exe startup message

// @ECHO OFF in CMD.exe
child.stdin.write('@ECHO OFF\r\n');
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    // @ECHO OFF  reply    (do nothing)
});


setTimeout(function () { // after 1 sec
    // remove prev stdout listener
    child.stdout.removeAllListeners('data');

    // new stdout listener
    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    // give input
    child.stdin.write('TIME /T\r\n');
}, 1000);
```

Problem is, instead of getting this output,

```
stdout: 06:05 PM
```

I'm getting this,

```
stdout: TIME /T
stdout: 06:23 PM
```

The command "TIME /T" which i have written to child's stdin is somehow getting written to its stdout.

If i do this on Command Prompt

```
 TIME /T > a.txt
```

only "06:23 PM" gets stored in a.txt, So cmd.exe's stdout is working fine. I guess the problem is in my nodejs code.

Where am i doing wrong? Any changes in spawn arguments?

If i use exec(), is there any way to maintain state(env, cwd etc) between child processes?

Any other suggestions? Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried passing /Q to cmd?